# Meaning of "подъезд"

Tags: существительные

When I look in dictionaries, they give me *driveway*, but then the following sentences don't really make sense. It sounds more like a part of a building (complex):

> Мы живем в одном **подъезде**.
>
> Моя квартира -- в четвертом **подъезде** на третьем этаже.
>
> Она работает консьержкой в нашем **подъезде**.
>
> Она убирает в нашем **подъезде**.

Comment: "ЧетверНом" or "четверТом"? "Четверной" is usually means something like "consisting of four parts".

Comment: @Artemix: I don't know - I copied those sentences from another source.

Comment: Well, then it most likely a typo and should be "четверТом" - never heard of подъезд "consisting of four parts", or of any other number of parts :)

Answer (score 14):

As an addition to @Artemix' answer, here's a picture of what a *подъезд* looks like. Usually buildings have several of them, they are counted from left to right, so the leftmost arrow points to the *первый подъезд*, the next one is *второй подъезд*, etc.

[image]

Comment: A picture's worth a thousand words! Thank you so much - that clears everything up. They're just entrances :)

Comment: @CocoPop - Well, yes, but not exactly. The staircase behind the door and all the appartments you can get to from the staircase also belong to the _подъезд_.

Answer (score 9):

Its "communal entrance hallway" or "entrance of an apartment building".
Other synonym is "парадное".

One building can have multiple entrances which lead to a different parts of a building.

> Мы живем в одном подъезде.

"We use common entrance to the apartment building".

> Моя квартира -- в четвертом подъезде на третьем этаже.

"My apartments are in the 4th entrance, on the third floor"

> Она работает консьержкой в нашем подъезде.

"She is a doorkeeper of the entrance we use"

> Она убирает в нашем подъезде.

"She cleans the entrance (and staircase, and other commonly used indoor spaces - hallway, corridors, elevators) we use".

Last example illustrates the idea of подъезд as a "section of an apartment building that uses single entrance".

Driveway is also correct, but "entrance" is more commonly used in cities.

Comment: There can be подъезд in non-residential building.

Answer (score 4):

`Подъезд` - is a (multilevel) block of appartments with a common entrance.
Another meaning *driveway* is also correct.